# Throwing a custom C# .Net exception does not get recognized by Axios in React

Tags: c#, reactjs, .net, typescript, axios

This is how I throw the exception:

`throw RestExceptionHandler.ThrowException(ErrorCode.WebServiceConnectorUnableToGetUser);`

This is the `ThrowException` method:

```
        public static RestServerException ThrowException(ErrorCode errorCode, object[] parameters = null, string property = null)
        {
            try
            {
                var value = ErrorCodes.errorList.First(code => code.errorCode == errorCode);

                if (parameters?.Length > 0)
                {
                    return new RestServerException(string.Format(value.description, parameters), 
                        value.httpStatusCode, new ErrorDescription
                        {
                            property = property ?? value.property,
                            errorCode = value.errorCode
                        });    
                }

                value.description = value.description.Replace("'{0}'", "");//removing placeholder {0} if there are no parameters given
                return new RestServerException(value.description, 
                    value.httpStatusCode, new ErrorDescription
                    {
                        property = property ?? value.property,
                        errorCode = value.errorCode
                    });

            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Log.Error(e, "Error: {@Exception}", e);
                throw;
            }
        }
```

This is the exception error body:

[image: error]

Now comes the React code, this is the post function in my service:

```
  getUser(request: any) {
    const res = axios
      .post<any, AxiosResponse<any>>("https://localhost:5002/v/1/signumid_integrations/user", request)
      .then((res) => {
        console.log(res);
        return res.data;
      })
      .catch(function (err) {
        console.log(err);
      });
    return res;
  }
```

And this is how I call the `getUser` method:

```
        httpClient
          .getUser(request)
          .then((res2) => {
           
            initiator.current =
              res2.mail === null || res2.mail === undefined || res2.mail === "" ? res2.userPrincipalName : res2.mail;
          });
```

And this is the Axios error that I get every time. It is a default empty network error every time.
[image: axios]

What could be the problem here and how do I solve it?

This is what the getUser method looks in network:
It returns 500, even though i set it to 400.

[image: getuser]

This is the controller in minimal api code:

```
app.MapPost("v/1/signumid_integrations/user", async (ExchangeOBORequest request) =>
    await IntegrationsService.GetUser(request));
```

Comment: Is your .NET code hit when debugging?

Comment: Yes @klekmek, it does

Comment: If you make a request through postman, is your response working as expected? Are you sure that your .NET API is working correctly? If so, then we'd need to look into the React code.

Comment: @MatejDodevski: In the browser's debugging tools, on the network tab, can you confirm the response from the server contains what you expect?

Comment: @David No, it does not but I don't know why... It returns 500 even though I set it to 400.

Comment: @MatejDodevski: At the very least, that tells you that the focus is on the server-side code and not the client-side code.  Which renders the current question moot, leading you "back to the drawing board" essentially.

Comment: But what specifically? I don't get it. This way of throwing errors is user through the whole code repository. Why doesn't it work here?

Comment: Can you post your controller code?

Comment: @klekmek I did post it now

Comment: Is there an `Exception` being thrown?

Comment: @klekmek Yes, look at the first line of code on this post

Comment: Why are you `throwing`  a method?